# How can one tell if DNS is being [on-machine] intercepted

Tags: macos, security, dns, privacy, proxy

On MacOS it is now possible for applications to insert a DNS proxy provider (i.e. using [nednsproxyprovider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nednsproxyprovider)) which intercepts all DNS requests.

How is it possible to discover, or list, whether such DNS proxy provider(s) is/are present (apart from just comparing a local DNS request with one made to an external DNS server)?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to see it in the syslog. There should be a message like this:

```
NESMDNSProxySession[SESSION CODE HERE]: status changed to connected
```